# System is automatically sending out email to Case "Contact Email"

Tags: web2case

When a case is created in our system via a Web 2 case webform, and the "Contact Email" is populated, Salesforce system sends a notification email to that email address with the following text:

> Your case # 00096902: Webform credit app submission has been updated.  Please click on the link below
>   to view this case on the Self-Service portal.

We don't run the "Self-Service portal" and would like to completely stop these emails. I cannot find any setting that controls this.

Notes:

1. "Visible in Self-Service Portal" was unchecked for the form code
2. We do have a public facing "Site" however Login is set to "Not Allowed"
3. I have found the template being sent -- however "Last Used Date" and
   "Times Used" are both empty.
4. I have reviewed all triggers, flows & process builders and none send the email notification.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your workflows and process builders?

Comment: @DavidCheng Yup. None sending an email notification. Also checked triggers.

Comment: In `Setup | Web to case Settings` do you have a response template defined?